# The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'zzzzzz, database 'xxxxxx' schema 'yyyyyy',

Tags: sql-server

I'm having problems executing a function...

Here's what I did:

1. create a function using SQL Server Management Studio. It was successfully created.
2. I then tried executing the newly created function and here's what I get:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on
>   the object 'xxxxxxx', database
>   'zzzzzzz', schema 'dbo'.